# "Advise <somebody> doing <something>" vs "suggest <somebody> doing <something>"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, pronouns

Are "**advise somebody doing** something" and "**suggest somebody doing** something" grammatically correct?

For example:

> I suggested us (rather than "we") going in my car.
>   I advised us (rather than "we") going in my car.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of "suggest", the two options that come to mind are:

> I suggested **going** in my car.

and

> I suggested **(that) we go** in my car.

You cannot say directly "to suggest **someone** something", nor can you say "to suggest **(to) do** something".
See further explanation on [English Teacher Melanie](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-how-to-use-the-verb-suggest/) and more examples of the correct usage of this verb on [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/suggest).

Using "advise" doesn't sound right in this context. If there were a third person saying it, the sentence could be:

> He advised **us to go** in my car.

More correct usage of "advise" on [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/advise).

Answer (score 1):

> I suggested us/we going in my car.
>
> I advised us/we going in my car.

Both the sentences are grammatically incorrect. You can rephrase these sentences with the use of the conjunction "that" as follows:

> I suggested that we go in my car.
>
> I advised  that we go in my car.

You can use "should" before the verb in these sentences in British English.

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid *'us'* does not work there. It should be 'we' as a pronoun in such context.

> I suggested (that) we go in my car.

I think when *you* are a part of that group, you can omit the pronoun 'we'.

> I suggested going in my car.

Comment: In your first suggested sentence, there shouldn't be a gerund.

Comment: I corrected the first suggested sentence.  Does retaining the gerund force the omission of the pronoun?

Comment: why not? @Tlacenka

Comment: @Jasper You can say either "I suggest **we do** something" using infinitive, or "I suggest **doing** something" with gerund but without pronoun...or simply "I suggest **something/someone** (e.g. a dish, potential employee)". In my answer, there is a link with more examples.

Comment: @Maulik V As for "*why not?*", there are simply different [patterns](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/flatmates/episode30/languagepoint.shtml) for different verbs...some verbs allow more than one pattern, some don't.

Comment: Oh, the answer is already edited...and I did not see that at all! Okay, I agree @Tlacenka I was just confused.